# How to store system settings in entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm currently doing system, which settings should be editable by admin. He cannot add them, but only choose/edit from existing one.

All the backend is done in **Sonata**.

Settings class:

```
class SystemSettings
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="key", type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $key;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $value;
}
```

Problem is that I have different value types to store. I have some booleans, lists, integers, etc. For example I want to display array of languages as a list, but when it comes to "posts on page" setting, user should be able to write down any integer he wants. Is there any proper way to store it and display?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using this method of storage is as you said, variable data types.  Soon you will want nested configuration, and eventually you will be writing over complex queries to select and update embedded JSON strings (trust me, i know).

I can't give you an exact solution because it is a problem I am still trying to solve.  However some solutions I have yet to explore include:

- Using MongoDB.  Because it stores data in JSON natively, it is fair more suited to storing arbitrary datatypes (within the range of scalar and arrays at least).
- Or dynamic file configuration.  Which is a writable file using XML, or JSON as a format to store arbitary data.  A problem you might run into though is if the server software is run on multiple machines.  However if you can implement the first solution, then this one is essentially the same.

In all cases, the configuration should be incorruptible in so far as if something is wrong, there should be static defaults for it to fall back on.  I am looking into adapting the Symfony\Component\Config component to achieve this.